# Positioning UIElement on a Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, wpf-controls, uielement, wpf-positioning

I have a canvas and a red rectangle laid on it. 
`Rectangle` has a `MouseDown` event handler implemented:

```
private void RedRectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    CreateMyBorder();
}
```

The `CreateMyBorder` method is supposed to create a `Border` UIElement with the same size and **position** as the rectangle on canvas, i.e. it is supposed to cover the red rectangle.

Copying the `Width` and `Height` properties of the red rectangle and setting them for the `Border` element is easy:

```
myBorder.Height = RedRectangle.Height;
myBorder.Width = RedRectangle.Width;
```

However, copying the position of the red rectangle on canvas seems impossible to me after 2 hours of trial and error! The expected:

```
double x = RedRectangle.GetValue(Canvas.Left);
double y = RedRectangle.GetValue(Canvas.Top);
myBorder.SetValue(Canvas.Left, x);
myBorder.SetValue(Canvas.Top, y);
```

doesn't work as the `x` and `y` variable values are `NaN`. Why?

Please help, I cannot believe that something as trivial as getting and setting the `UIElement`'s position on a panel can be so irritating. Thanks.

Comment: GetValue returns an object too - you should cast it as double e.g. `(double)RedRectangle.GetValue(Canvas.Top);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the static functions on `Canvas`:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(element, x);
Canvas.SetTop(element, y);
```

Beware, `Canvas` never display elements with `Left` or `Top` equal to `double.NaN`, which is the default value for `Left` and `Top`.

Comment: Simon, thanks for the reply. This should solve the setter side for the `Border`. But how am I supposed to get the red rectangle's `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties? The way I wrote above always returns `NaN`.

Comment: Same idea: double left = Canvas.GetLeft(rectangle) to get rectangle's left.

Comment: It is worth noting two things: (1)that unless `Canvas.Left` is explicitly set, it will return NaN and (2) If you set `Canvas.Left` of an element, it may not actually reflect that setting. To exemplify this, set both `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Right` of the same element, then print out the values of `Canvas.GetLeft()` and `Canvas.GetRight()`.